# How is the Google Maps API V3 accessed using Delphi XE5 Firemonkey Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-api-3, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I've found an excellent blog post http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/ that seems to outline a reasonable methodology for utilizing the Google Maps API from a Delphi application.  Unfortunately, it does not port to Firemonkey Mobile.  The Windows TWebBrowser control has a .Document property, but the FMX.TWebBrowser does not.  Uses MSHTML is not valid for a Firemonkey Mobile application.  Neither is "uses ActiveX".

This seems like it would be common functionality for a mobile device with a GPS sensor.

I've been searching, but the best I've come up with for the Firemonkey Mobile application is:

```
myMapURL := 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + strLatitude + ',' + strLongitude + '&output=embed';
webLocationMap.Navigate(myMapURL);
```

I haven't found a static call that produces a map with a highlighted route, and I can't locate an example that shows how to run an execScript against a Firemonkey TWebBrowser.

I've been successful getting the XML directions back using this code:

```
var lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
var LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
lHTTP.IOHandler:=LHandler;
myString := lHTTP.Get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=my+address,state&destination=where+to+go,state&sensor=false');
```

but I'm not finding any examples on using the returned info to create/display a map with the route highlighted.

Just to restate the question: How can I use the Google Maps API V3 in a Delphi Firemonkey Mobile app to get turn by turn directions and display a map with the route highlighted?

Oh, the target for the application is Android and iOS now, adding Windows Phone in the future.

Thank You!

Comment: Well, unless anyone has a better answer, I'm going to generate a URL as follows:  maps.google.com/maps?saddr=lat,lon&daddr=street+address+or+lat,lon&sensor=TRUE  Not nearly as functional as the desktop sample referenced, but it gets me a map and I can move on to the next task.  Thanks for reading.